# How is volume size of HostPath mount determined?

Tags: kubernetes

Now I got a logs volume:

```
      - name: log
        hostPath:
          path: /opt/cloud/logs/sample
```

and when I execute `cd /opt/cloud/logs/sample;df -h .`, it shows：

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        40G   11G   27G  29% /opt/cloud/logs/sample
```

My question is: where is the 40G number came from? Is there a way to limit this to another number like 30GB? What happens if the container used up 40G, get evicted or the disk size just magically bump to a higher number?

#### Edit

I just find out 40G is the size of host disk. But if I use an emptyDir instead of hostPath, it only got 9.8G size，which corresponded to size of `/mnt/paas/kubernetes/kubelet` on the host, which I have no idea what it is or why it is 9.8G.

k8s version:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.9", GitCommit:"16236ce91790d4c75b79f6ce96841db1c843e7d2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-03-25T06:40:24Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13+", GitVersion:"v1.13.10-r1-CCE2.0.28.B001", GitCommit:"0de6083f712a799642f25141c60fdeff34d5514c", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-10-30T14:19:27Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.13", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: Can you share more information about your environment? Like where are you running your cluster, Kubernetes version etc.?

Answer (score 1):

- where is the 40G number came from?

The [`hostPath`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) volume type is a node filesystem volume, volume is determined by the medium of the filesystem holding the kubelet root dir.

- Is there a way to limit this to another number like 30GB?

There is no limit on how much space an `emptyDir` or `hostPath` volume can consume, and no isolation between `Containers` or between `Pods`.

- What happens if the container used up 40G, get evicted or the disk size just magically bump to a higher number?

Your pod will have `write error` because the filesystem will be full.

Comment: As for the second problem, I tried myself and got: Warning  Evicted    20m   kubelet, 192.168.0.220  The node was low on resource: [DiskPressure].

Comment: I dont get what you mean.

Comment: When disk space used up, that container will be evicted instead of write error.